# Checkbox from custom ListAdapter not receiving clicks

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a custom `ListAdapter` with elements consisting of a single `TextView` and `CheckBox`. Problem is checkboxes don't receive any click events.

Adapter's code below.

```
public DragNDropAdapter(Context context) {
        mViews = new View[mTexts.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < mViews.length; i++) {
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText(mTexts[i]);
            layout.addView(textView);

            CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(context);
            checkBoxView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    log("clicked"); //doesn't work
                }
            });
            layout.addView(checkBoxView);

            mViews[i] = layout;
        }
    }

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return mViews[position];
    }
```

Nothing happens when chechboxes are clicked. However when I turn the screen and everything is "automatically recreated" all missing logs are shown together.

Question is, what and why is withholding those click events?

Previously I had it like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText(mTexts[position]);
            layout.addView(textView);

            CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(context);
            checkBoxView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    log("clicked");//do work
                }
            });
            layout.addView(checkBoxView);

            convertView = layout;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //(...) setting holder's info

        return convertView;
    }
```

And click events were passed correctly. What is the difference? I can't use second approach, because it is a drag and drop adapter, and I wasn't able to find a good way of tracking checkboxes statuses.

To sum up - why click events don't work in first approach, but do work in the second one?

Comment: onCheckedChangeListener instaed of onClick for Checkbox

Comment: @kalyanpvs None listener works. onClick was just an example and should work fine

Comment: then why you posted question as nbot receiveing clicks clarrify your question..

Comment: @kalyanpvs it was simpler that way. CheckBox should receive click events, when onClickListener is set. And it does receive them in second case, but not in the first one. Question is, why is that so?
Please note, that in both cases CheckBox is created in precisely the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(context);
```

instead of

```
CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(mContext);
```

And how people already said - use OnCheckedChangedListener

Comment: That is the same Context, but I will edit the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it (assuming you get your checkbox from holder .. correctly) :

```
holder.(checkboxNameInTheHolder).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // Your stuff
 }
});
```

Hope that helped.
Regards.

Comment: Find it from where? I am creating checkboxes in presented methods, not inflating them

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't pay attention to that. i'm currently doing this in one of my projects, i'm using setOnCheckedChangeListener() method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(context);
        checkBoxView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("clicked");//do work
            }
        });
        layout.addView(checkBoxView);
```

To

```
        CheckBox checkBoxView = new CheckBox(context);
        layout.addView(checkBoxView); 
        checkBoxView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("clicked");//do work
            }
        });
```

OR(Recommended):

```
 checkBoxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
 if(isChecked)
 log("clicked");//do work
}
```